# Adding and listing JSON to the cookie

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I want to add JSON data to the browser cookie and then list the added JSON data in a DIV. However, I am getting an error in the console. What could be the reason for this and where am I going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var obj = [{
     "file-postSender_revize1.png": {
       "asrs": "gi",
       "name": "postSender_revize1.png",
       "life": "48",
       "type": "parcel"
     }
   },{
     "file-postSender_revize2.png": {
       "asrs": "gi",
       "name": "postSender_revize2.png",
       "life": "24",
       "type": "parcel"
     }
   }];

   document.cookie = "uploadFiles=" + obj;
   var str = JSON.stringify(getCookie('uploadFiles'));
   var json = JSON.parse(str);
   for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     document.getElementById('fileList').innerHTML += json[i].name;
   }

 });

 function getCookie(name) {
   const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
   const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
   if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
 }
```

Console:

```
"jQuery.Deferred exception: \&quot;undefined\&quot; is not valid JSON", "SyntaxError: \&quot;undefined\&quot; is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
    at HTMLDocument.&lt;anonymous&gt; (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:124:20)
    at mightThrow (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js:3557:29)
    at process (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js:3625:12)", undefined
```

Comment: Your getCookie function return undefined, and it causes an error when you try to JSON.parse it. Anyway i would use localStorage and not cookie to store a json object. Also dont try to stringify it, it's already a string at that point.

Comment: @Lk77 Thank you for your help, I started using localStorage with your suggestion and you can see it in this demo. However, I still could not print the JSON data. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/nhLzp7kx/)

Comment: You need to stringify your object before storing it in localStorage, and parse it after retrieving it from localStorage.

Comment: @Lk77 I'm already doing before localStorage with `JSON.stringify` (line 18 ?) How can I make the parcel because it is dynamic key?

Comment: Show us the code you've tried with localStorage, right now it's difficult to say what's wrong.

Comment: @Lk77 Link : [Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/nhLzp7kx/)

Comment: The store/retrieve part do work, but the part when you use the json don't work, because you need to go deeper in the json structure, `json[0]` is worth   `{file-postSender_revize1.png: {asrs: 'gi', name: 'postSender_revize1.png', life: '48', type: 'parcel'}}`. I guess you need to change your json structure to something else, like : `[{}, {}]`

Comment: @Lk77 Yes, I know but it's impossible for now. So is there a way to print it?

Comment: @Lk77 I just saw your reply. This is great! You can write it as an answer if you want, and I'd like to accept it. Teşekkür ederim.

Comment: done, i've moved my comments in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the json structure, right now you have something like `[ {{}}, {{}} ]`, and i would make `[ {}, {} ]`

If you want to keep the depth as is, you will have to iterate over the keys like so :

```js
Object.keys(json[i]).forEach(k => { 
   console.log(json[i][k].name) 
})
```